# Handling Multiple "Screens" In Android via TableLayouts

Tags: android, xml, screen, visibility, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to make an Options "Menu" Screen. When the menu button is pressed the menu comes up with a "button" that says Options when that is clicked, the function clicks a button called optionsButton. When that button is pressed I want one TableLayout to become Invisible and one to become visible.

Here is the code I have to hide the layouts.

```
public void optionButton(View view)
{
    TableLayout mainTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableMain);
    TableLayout optionTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableOptions);
    mainTable.setVisibility(TableLayout.INVISIBLE);
    optionTable.setVisibility(TableLayout.VISIBLE);

}
```

And here is the XML that handles my optionButton `<Button android:onClick="optionButton" android:id="@+id/optionsButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:visibility="invisible"></Button>`

And here is the code that handles my "Menu Button"

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.options:
        Button optbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.optionsButton);
        optbtn.performClick();
        break;
    default:

        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that when the menu button is clicked, nothing happens. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you debug and see if your code enters your first case in function onOptionsItemSelected(..) also print value of R.id.options & item.getItemId() in that function if it does not go in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting the optionsTable and all of it's contents. Remaking it and putting it below the mainTable in the Graphical Editor of main.xml